simple_calendar error when updating rails from 5.1 to 7.1
Have an old Rails app that was just updated, which uses simple_calendar gem, which is now giving me this error:
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `block' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000112920>):
    34:                 <% capture_haml(day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []), &block) %>
    35:               <% else %>
    36:                 <% block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
    37:               <% end %>
    38:             <% end %>
    39:           <% end %>
    40:         </tr>
  
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:37
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:33
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:32:in `each'
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:32
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:30:in `each'
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:30:in `each_slice'
app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb:30
app/views/ashphidmodal/_schedule.html.erb:1
app/views/ashphidmodal/scheduleMain.js.erb:5

the whole code is:
<div class="simple-calendar">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <% date_range.slice(0, 7).each do |day| %>
          <th><p class="small"><%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %></p></th>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% date_range.each_slice(7) do |week| %>
        <tr>
          <% week.each do |day| %>
            <%= content_tag :td, class: calendar.td_classes_for(day) do %>
              <% if defined?(Haml) && respond_to?(:block_is_haml?) && block_is_haml?(block) %>
                <% capture_haml(day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []), &block) %>
              <% else %>
                <% block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

I would troubleshoot this but a global search for any of those variables result in nothing (date_range, block etc), so I have no idea where they're coming from.  This code worked previous in Rails 5.1.
... in Rails 5.1 block is something called a "proc" which points to line 1 in a file called _schedule.html.erb which is:
<%= month_calendar events: @all_events do |date, events| %>

... so from that I can ascertain that month_calendar is being rendered but not with some proc sent from _schedule.html.erb:1. I've followed the path through the controller to the view, and everything progresses normally, but no block is generated when month_calendar is rendered (if that's what's happening)
possibly this error is because Rails 5.1 simple_calendar version was 2.2.5 and in this Rails 7.1.3.4 the simple_calendar version is 3.0.4?
should i try reducing the simple_calendar back down to 2.2.5? (or "~> 2.0" in gemfile etc)

do you need to override simple calendar's _month_calendar partial? if not, just remove that file. otherwise you need to update it https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar/blob/v3.0.4/app/views/simple_calendar/_month_calendar.html.erb

Specifically, I updated the file with that from the link and it worked, I appreciate that, thank you. This begs the question, where does gem code live (I don't understand the general flow), but I will put that in queue for now.
